# Socket.io does not emit if the data is too big

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I've build a webapp that can send images. For small pictures everything works fine. But as soon as it gets a little bigger ~1000x1000px, socket.io does not emit. It does not even state an error. It just does not send the image.

This is what my Object looks like:

```
chatBlock = {
username: "",
message: "",
date: new Date(),
file: null,
imgWidth: 0,
imgHeight: 0,
};
```

and thats how I send it:

```
socket.emit('msgSend', chatBlock);
```

So actually pretty basic, but as soon as the image (named file in the object) gets to big, it does not send it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Socket.io has a message size limit: see option `maxHttpBufferSize` in the docs at https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#maxhttpbuffersize .
You can increase this limit, but keep in mind that parsing images as JSON is not very efficient. In the long term, consider uploading the images separately - a common solution is to use HTTP POST, obtain the uploaded URL, and send that to the recipient instead. This is more complex, but avoids the message size problem entirely, as file uploads can be of any size and still be streamed in an efficient manner.

Comment: Answer is almost perfect. The link is incorrect though. This is the address you are looking for: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#maxhttpbuffersize

Comment: @Nadav I've replaced the link, thank you.

Comment: HI. Could you elaborate a bit on this "a common solution is to use HTTP POST, obtain the uploaded URL, and send that to the recipient instead".   
1. Who is doing http post and for what?   
2. How do we obtain the uploaded URL? This is part of the problem, that in browser JS we cannot obtain the uploaded URL.

Answer (score 0):

As the the [official docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#maxhttpbuffersize) says you should use **maxhttpbuffersize**

In case of express is being used:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(
  server,{
    maxHttpBufferSize: 1e7
  }
)
```

But the value is something martian. It is called **SI prefixes**

The [SI prefix](https://www.convertunits.com/info/mega+bytes) **mega** represents a factor of 106, or in exponential notation, 1E6.

Here some values to use as **maxhttpbuffersize**

- 1e6 = 1mb
- 1e7 = 10mb
- 1e8 = 100mb which is is the [max-payload accepted](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#new-websocketserveroptions-callback)

Here some values : https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html

[image]

> PD: I did not find how to set 1.5 mb